# Why does Google Pixel 6's camera add some artefact when using `.7x`?

Tags: noise, google

Example of artefact using the native camera application with `.7x`:

[image]

Camera with `1x` shows no such artefact:

[image]

`1x` and `.7x` settings:

[image]

Comment: Online images suggest it has three distinct cameras - there's the possibility one is damaged, or has a software glitch.

Comment: @Tetsujin I just [saw](https://www.phonearena.com/news/pixel-6-camera_id135832) 2 cameras on the rear of the Pixel 6, and 3 only on the rear of the Pixel 6 Pro.

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/GooglePixel/comments/tzad8j/comment/i3xpw9r/ seems to confirm that .7 and 1 are the two lenses, 2x is digital zoom, and the pro has an additional 4x tele lens. OP can easily test which lens is used by covering them with a finger.